# How to highlight a specific tree node in xpage programmatically?

Tags: dojo, xpages

I have a dijit.tree in xpage. I want to select a specific tree node when the page is rendered. 
In dojo reference guide,There is a example contains workaround code for this problem, as well as an example call to tree.attr('path') if you already know the full path to the tree node you want to highlight. But i want to highlight the node automaticlly when the page is rendered.
What's the more idiomatic way of doing this? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a XSP.addOnload(function(){....}) call in an Outputscript element to render the highlight.

Comment: Glad to help. Post a working example somewhere- trees are of common interest.